# PyGame Vector Only Gravity Function not Working

Tags: python, vector, pygame

When creating a vector only game in PyGame (movement and location use vectors) and attempting to make a planetary style centered gravity, the gravitation pull is inconsistent. Here is the code for the gravity function:

```py
import math
import pygame
import time

class movementObj:

    def __init__(self, posX = 0.0, posY = 0.0, currentVelocity = [0,0], maxVelocity = 20.0):
        self.x = posX
        self.y = posY
        self.vel = currentVelocity
        self.maxVel = maxVelocity

    def gravity(self, pos, val):
        pos = self.__subVec(pos,[self.x,self.y])
        currentSpeed = math.sqrt(math.pow(pos[0]-self.x,2)+math.pow(pos[1]-self.y,2))
        change = val / currentSpeed
        pos = self.__mulVec(pos,change)
        self.accelerate(pos)
        return pos
```

Here is the whole code:

```py
import math
import pygame
import time

class movementObj:

    def __init__(self, posX = 0.0, posY = 0.0, currentVelocity = [0,0], maxVelocity = 20.0):
        self.x = posX
        self.y = posY
        self.vel = currentVelocity
        self.maxVel = maxVelocity

    def __addVec(self, vectorOne, vectorTwo):
        returnVec = [(vectorOne[i] + vectorTwo[i]) for i in range(len(vectorOne))]
        return returnVec

    def __mulVec(self,vectorOne,mulValue):
        returnVec = [(i*mulValue) for i in vectorOne]
        return returnVec

    def resistance(self,val):
        self.vel = self.__mulVec(self.vel,1-val)

    def gravity(self, pos, val):
        # pos = self.__subVec(pos,[self.x,self.y])
        # spd =  math.sqrt(math.pow(pos[0]-self.x,2)+math.pow(pos[1]-self.y,2))
        # over = spd-val
        # overPercent = 1-(over/spd)
        # pos = self.__mulVec(pos,overPercent)
        # # print(pos,end="\r")
        # self.accelerate(pos)
        # return overPercent
        pos = self.__subVec(pos,[self.x,self.y])
        currentSpeed = math.sqrt(math.pow(pos[0]-self.x,2)+math.pow(pos[1]-self.y,2))
        change = val / currentSpeed
        pos = self.__mulVec(pos,change)
        self.accelerate(pos)
        return pos

    def __getSpeed(self):
        return math.sqrt(math.pow(self.vel[0],2)+math.pow(self.vel[1],2))

    def __subVec(self, vectorOne, vectorTwo):
        returnVec = [(vectorOne[i] - vectorTwo[i]) for i in range(len(vectorOne))]
        return returnVec
        
    def updatePos(self):
        self.x += self.vel[0]
        self.y += self.vel[1]
        self.normalizeVelocity()
        # print(str(self.vel[0]-self.x) + "," + str(self.vel[1]-self.y), end="\r")

    def accelerate(self, acc):
        self.vel = self.__addVec(self.vel,acc)
    
    def normalizeVelocity(self):
        currentSpeed = self.__getSpeed()
        if self.x > 400:
            self.x = self.x-400
            self.y = 400-self.y
        if self.x < 0:
            self.y = 400-self.y
            self.x = self.x+400
        if self.y > 400:
            self.x = 400-self.x
            self.y = self.y-400
        if self.y < 0:
            self.x = 400-self.x
            self.y = self.y+400
        if currentSpeed < self.maxVel:
            return
        over = currentSpeed-self.maxVel
        overPercent = 1-(over/currentSpeed)
        self.vel = self.__mulVec(self.vel,overPercent)
        

    def start(self):
        print(self.__getSpeed())




size = 400
obj = movementObj()
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([size, size])
def gameloop():
    counter = 0
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                return

        keys=pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            obj.accelerate([0,0.2])
        if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
            obj.accelerate([0,-0.2])
        if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            obj.accelerate([-0.2,0])
        if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            obj.accelerate([0.2,0])  

        gline = obj.gravity([200,200],0.1)
        # print(gline, end="\r")
        # obj.resistance(0.015)
        
        screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
        pygame.draw.line(screen, (0,0,255), (obj.x,obj.y), (obj.x+(1000*gline[0]),obj.y+(1000*gline[1])), 2)
        pygame.draw.line(screen, (0,255,0), (obj.x,obj.y), (obj.x+(10*obj.vel[0]),obj.y+(10*obj.vel[1])), 2)
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, (0, 0, 0), (obj.x,obj.y), 1)
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, (0, 0, 0), (200,200), 1)
        pygame.display.flip()
        obj.updatePos()
        # obj.accelerate([0.08,-0.08])
        time.sleep(50/1000)
        counter += 1
import sys
gameloop()
sys.stdout.close()
pygame.quit()
```

When running it, the goal is to have consistent acceleration towards the center from any location on the plane, but instead it is inconsistent. Any ideas why?
(photos of the problem: green is the velocity, blue is acceleration)

[image: Too much acceleration on top left]
[image: Too little anywhere else]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to simplify the code and to use [`pygame.math.Vector2`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html#pygame.math.Vector2) for the calculations. Very handy is the [`scale_to_length`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html#pygame.math.Vector2.scale_to_length)  method, which scales the vector to a certain length. This function can also be used to limit the length of a vector. Of course you can do the math your own, however I strongly suggest to introduce helper functions like `normalize` and `scale_to_lenght`.

```py
import pygame
import sys

class MovementObj:
    def __init__(self, posX = 0.0, posY = 0.0, currentVelocity = [0,0], maxVelocity = 5.0):
        self.pos = pygame.math.Vector2(posX, posY)
        self.vel = pygame.math.Vector2(currentVelocity)
        self.maxVel = maxVelocity

    def gravity(self, target, accVal):
        acc = pygame.math.Vector2(target) - self.pos
        if acc.length() > 0:
            acc.scale_to_length(accVal)
        self.accelerate(acc)
        return acc

    def updatePos(self):
        self.pos += self.vel

    def accelerate(self, acc):
        self.vel += acc
        if self.vel.length() > self.maxVel:
            self.vel.scale_to_length(self.maxVel)
    
size = 400
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([size, size])
def gameloop():
    obj = MovementObj()
    clock = pygame.time.Clock() 
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                return

        keys=pygame.key.get_pressed()
        ax = (keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] - keys[pygame.K_LEFT]) * 0.2
        ay = (keys[pygame.K_DOWN] - keys[pygame.K_UP]) * 0.2
        obj.accelerate([ax, ay])  

        gline = obj.gravity([200,200], 0.1)
        obj.updatePos()
        
        screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, (0, 0, 0), obj.pos, 5)
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, (0, 0, 0), (200, 200), 5)
        pygame.draw.line(screen, (0, 0, 255), obj.pos, obj.pos + gline * 200, 2)
        pygame.draw.line(screen, (255, 0, 0), obj.pos, obj.pos + obj.vel * 5, 2)
        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(20)

gameloop()
sys.stdout.close()
pygame.quit()
```